# Python's Subprocess input pipe keeps breaking on a specific machine

Tags: python, subprocess

I wrote a script that uses the subprocess module to access remote services via sshpadd and gather some information, which was working fine on my local machine and several virtual machines, but not so much on the machine I'll deploy it at, as the input PIPE keeps breaking (Write failed: Broken Pipe)

At first I thought the bug is somehow with sshpass and ssh connection, I tried changing my ssh_config to include a KeepAlive part to make sure the connection is never closed (which shouldn't be the case anyways since my script doesn't take that long to run, just access the remote house, run a couple of command and log the output).

I think the issue is with the subprocess module and the input pipe to be specific, when using subprocess.Popen with another module, it works when I use the communicate function, but at that same part when I use input pipe lines and try to user `write()` and `flush()` i get the same "Broken Pipe" error.

I am not sure what to do next, especially since this bug occurs only on the virtual machine where I (ironically) must deploy the script eventually. All other VMs I've tried and my local machine run the script with no problem.

```py
sshpass = ['sshpass', '-p', 'password', 'ssh', '-tt', '-o' , 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=5', '-o', 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null', 'root@host']

ssh_process = subprocess.Popen(sshpass, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

ssh_process.stdin.write(b'\n\)
ssh.stdin.flush()
```

Any idea what might be wrong here? I ruled out ssh configuration completely since I copied the same configs from a machine where the code is working and it was running fine, what else could be causing this?